# No module name netmiko on Centos

Tags: python, centos7, netmiko

It is my first time to use netmiko module on Centos.

I kept get below message when I was using Python(2.7.5).

[image]

If I used Python(3.6.8), it will be this:

[image]

I have verified that I did install netmiko.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install netmiko`?

Comment: Please don't post text as images. It makes the search not to find it.

Comment: Uninstall your current netmiko version which is `3.3.2`. Then install `netmiko 2.3.2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably might be an issue due to different python versions in your system. Perhaps you can install it by calling `pip` module of the particular python version.

So, for **python 3.x** you can execute the following:

```
python3 -m pip install netmiko
```

Similarly, for **python 2.x** you can execute:

```
python -m pip install netmiko
```

Comment: Based on the error, it won't work with Python2 since f-strings are used

Comment: @OneCricketeer That is a good point. If you don't mind I'll mention your point in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried python 3.x command which works well.

```
python3 -m pip install netmiko
```

The python 2.x command did not work.
It seems like latest netmiko did not support python version under 3.x anymore.